# How to upload a csv file and then parse its content with Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, loops, csv

I already have a PHP script to upload a CSV file: it's a collection of tweets associated to a Twitter account (aka a brand). BTW, Thanks T.A.G.S :)

I also have a script to parse this CSV file: I need to extract emojis, hashtags, links, retweets, mentions, and many more details I need to compute for each tweet (it's for my research project: digital affectiveness. I've already stored 280k tweets, with 170k emojis inside).

Then each tweet and its metrics are saved in a database (table TWEETS), as well as emojis (table EMOJIS), as well as account stats (table BRANDS).

I use a class quite similar to this one: CsvImporter > https://gist.github.com/Tazeg/b1db2c634651c574e0f8. I made a loop to parse each line 1 by 1.

```
$importer = new CsvImporter($uploadfile,true); 
        while($content = $importer->get(1)) {
            $pack = $content[0];
            $data = array();
            foreach($pack as $key=>$value) {
                $data[]= $value;
            }
            $id_str = $data[0];
            $from_user = $data[1];
```

...

After all my computs, I `"INSERT INTO TWEETS VALUES(...)"`, same with `EMOJIS`. The after, I have to make some other operations

1. update reach for each id_str, if a tweet I saved is a reply to a previous tweet)
2. save stats to table BRAND

All these operations are scripted in a single file, insert.php, and triggered when I submit my upload form.
But everything falls down if there is too many tweets. My server cannot handle so long operations.

So I wonder if I can ajaxify parts of the process, especially the loop

1. upload the file
2. parse 1 CSV line and save it in SQL and display a 'OK' message each time a tweet is saved
3. compute all other things (reach and brand stats)

I'm not enough aware of `$.ajax()` but I guess there is something to do with beforeSend, success, complete and all the Ajax Events. Or maybe am I completely wrong!?

Is there anybody who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can lighten the load on your server substantially because `$pack` is an array of values already, and there is no need to do the `key value` loop.

You can also write the mapping of values from the CSV row more idiomatically. Unless you know the CSV file is likely to be huge, you should also do multiple lines

```php
$importer = new CsvImporter($uploadfile, true);
// get as many lines as possible at once...
while ($content = $importer->get()) {
    // this loop works whether you get 1 row or many...
    foreach ($content as $pack) {
        list($id_str, $from_user, ...) = $pack;
        // rest of your line processing and SQL inserts here....
    }
}
```

You could also go on from this and insert multiple lines into your database in a single `INSERT` statement, which is supported by most SQL databases.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. The load time has reduced indeed. But I'm still facing time-out problems. I know there is a lot to do with queries/loops optimization. I still wonder if ajax could help me here

Comment: AJAX is performed (normally) within the remote browser, and there is nothing that you can do within the browser that would improve the performance of storing your data in the database. You still have to have a script on the server which parses the uploaded CSV file. You could parse the CSV file on the browser and send a whole sequence of AJAX calls to insert each row 1 by 1, but this would be slow. 

You could alternatively respond to the call of your script before you finished processing the data, provided you just validate it first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = fopen($filepath, "r");
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f, 10000, ",")) !== false) {
    array_push($entries, $line);
}
fclose($f);
```

try this, it may help.